# Generators of the Poincaré group

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, poincare-symmetry

I am specifically interested in constructing the generators of an Poincaré group for a 2+1 dimensional Euclidean field theory. But I am pretty new to the subject, so I would like to ask some basic questions.

I know the form of the Poincaré Algebra and I know how to proceed from the algebra to obtain Casimir invariants, but I have not found a book that explains which specific representations the generators (that obtain the commutation relations) have for the common scalar, spinor or vector field. I guess I have to start from infinitesimal field transformations, could someone help me?

Comment: Euclidean 2+1 dimensions? 2 space + 1 space? Or did you mean Minkowski?

Comment: I mean Euclidean with metric $\eta_{\mu\nu} = \delta_{\mu\nu}$ and 2 spatial dimensions + 1 time dimension. But i am happy with answers for the standard, Minkowski 4d case

Comment: If a flat metric is just the Kronecker delta, it is called Euclidean. In contrast, if there is one time dimension then it is Minkowski, in any dimension (greater than two)

Comment: I think we both mean the same. I guess my formulation of my 3d space as 2+1 is misleading. I really mean 3 spacetime dimensions with a flat metric.

Comment: the misleading part is when you write "Euclidean" when it really is Minkowski. The 2+1 part is clear. As for your question, you can find a number of lecture notes and reviews online. Search for representation theory of Lorentz (or Poincare) group.

Comment: I only find sources where they say "the generators for a scalar field are....". I do not find a deviation

Comment: Start from the explicit expressions of [Minkowski generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#Explicit_formulas) and weed out the 3rd dimension, chucking out all generators involving it, so discard 1 boost and two rotations, and one momentum. The rest should be self-explanatory.

Comment: @roran_physician then those are probably definitions. You can also check out Lie groups and representation theory of Lie groups for more

Comment: @CosmasZachos i know how they look. I just wonder if one can derive them from the expected transformation behavior, e.g $\prime \Phi = \Phi$; $\prime \psi = S \psi$

Comment: Just emulate 3+1?    .

Comment: I finally found something, for those interested http://cftp.ist.utl.pt/~gernot.eichmann/2015-qft/qft-2.pdf, on page 29-30.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you, it works the way stated in the source, as you said similar in 3+1 and in 2+1. Thanks for the help

Comment: How Poincare generators act on scalar, spinor or vector field is pretty much the definition of the scalar, spinor or vector field.

Comment: @Peter Kravchuk yes this confused me. Most books etc. define the generators and show that they act on the fields as we want them to do. For me, it was the other way round. I found the generators via imposing that they have a certain behavior for the specific feld.